# DateTime from database leaves 00.00.001

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having this problem that when i use:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blogTitle)</h3>
        <p>**@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.blogCreated)**</p>
    </div>
```

(The item.blogCreated is a datetime object)

In my mssql database have i set the column to be a datetime.

As model i got this one:

```
public partial class Blogs
    {
        public int blogId { get; set; }
        public string blogTitle { get; set; }
        public string blogContent { get; set; }
        public int blogWriter { get; set; }
        public DateTime? blogCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

And a Context this:

```
 public partial class McbomanEntities : DbContext
    {
        public McbomanEntities()
            : base("name=McbomanEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Blogs> Blogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Do anyone know how i can change so that item.blogCreated will give the actual date of when the blog was created and not the date of when jesus was born.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove the old database model and reload new entity database model.